# location based url codeigniter mvc from query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, url, routes

Setup
Codeigniter, MVC (test dataset is OSClass DB)

Problem
Have 3 queries to get the needed geographic data into the model and passed into the controller. Can not merge these queries and use "s_slug" column values as "slug".

Note - CI has limits and can not echo the entire city dataset. That limit isn't something I wish to change.

Question
Would creating hierarchical folders in view solve some of my issues? location/country/state/city
How do I use this data to generate slugs THAT WILL generate url's?
Scope of test dataset is just shy of 28k entries on 3 tables. My actual dataset is almost 10k larger. Using this method, what is to be expected in adverse server performance due to load? I just don't know another way to create so many links.

In the front end url's are easy...I'm at a bit of a loss trying to control a front end function from the back (due to the massive scale I need) At least that's how I'm used to viewing the problem. hmmm.....
did create hyperlinks in the view page (data test) but they are empty and obviously resolve to a 404.

Below is what I'm using so far. (subject to change)

Route(s)
'$route['geo/(:any)'] = "geo/";'
(a slight mod to a previous suggestion..was keeping door wide open to test data)

MODEL

```
<?php
class GeoModel extends CI_Model {

function getCountries() {
    $this->db->select("s_name,s_slug");
    $this->db->from('oc_t_country');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}

function getStates(){
  $this->db->select("pk_i_id,fk_c_country_code,s_name,s_slug");
  $this->db->from('oc_t_region');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
}

function getCities() {
  $this->db->select("pk_i_id,fk_i_region_id,s_name,s_slug");
  $this->db->from('oc_t_city');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
}

function getCatStruct() {
  $this->db->select("pk_i_id,fk_i_parent_id,i_position,b_enabled");
  $this->db->from('t_category');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
}

function getCatDescrip () {
  $this->db->select("fk_i_category_id,s_name,s_slug");
  $this->db->from('t_category_description');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
}

}
?>
```

Controller

```
<?php
class Geo extends CI_Controller {

function __Construct(){
  parent::__Construct ();
   $this->load->database(); // load database
   $this->load->model('GeoModel'); // load model
   //$this->load->helper('url');
}

public function index() {
   $this->data['countries'] = $this->GeoModel->getCountries();
   $this->data['states'] = $this->GeoModel->getStates(); // calling State model method getStates()
   $this->data['cities'] = $this->GeoModel->getCities(); 
   $this->data['catstruct'] = $this->GeoModel->getCatStruct();
   $this->data['catdescrip'] = $this->GeoModel->getCatDescrip();

   //$segments =array('countries','states','cities');
   //echo site_url($segments);

   $this->load->view('geo_view', $this->data); // load the view file , we are passing $data array to view file
}

}

?>
```

View (just to test data was passing successfully)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>

<!-- In table format we display all state names from chosen DB Table with their id numbers. State name is used for name and State slug is used for link--> 
    <h4>List of States</h4>
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td><strong>State Name</strong></td>
      <td><strong>State ID#</strong></td>
    </tr>
     <?php foreach($states as $state){?>
     <tr>
         <td><a href="/geo/<?php echo $state->s_slug;?>"><?php echo $state->s_name;?></td>
         <td><?php echo $state->pk_i_id;?></td>
      </tr>    
     <?php }?>  
   </table>
 <!--  This section commented out - demo of how list with (currently empty) links can be created with 5 lines of code
   <?php foreach($states as $state){?>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="/geo/<?php echo $post->s_slug;?>"><?php echo $post->s_slug;?></a></li>
   </ul>
    <?php }?>
    -->

    <h4>List of All Catagories (not sorted)</h4>
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td><strong>Cat Name</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Cat ID#</strong></td>
    </tr>
     <?php foreach($catdescrip as $cdes){?>
     <tr>
         <td><a href="/geo/<?php echo $cdes->s_slug;?>"><?php echo $cdes->s_name;?></td>
         <td><?php echo $cdes->fk_i_category_id;?></td>
      </tr>    
     <?php }?>  
   </table>


  </body>
</html>
```

In the model I also have queries for the Catagories (2 tables to create the id relationship necessary to create hierarchical structure in a flat relational DB) For now ignore those. Upon reconsideration, it would be better to handle this shorter list thru HTML & PHP templating. Trying to take the same list, append it to 30k individual pages, read the url and append new values to create 30k values for each category. That's too much load for both CI and a Mysql DB. That alone would be double pinging the DB each and every time any page loads. It would crawl to a halt.

Any sanity you can bring to this hot mess is greatly appreciated!

Comment: UPDATE - Scraped all of this code. Goal can not be achieved thru this method. Attempting to apply Segments, URI control or routing results in either no pages or no url control what so ever i.e. yoursite.com/typeAnyProfanityAndStillGetaPage. Am also evaluating that this is likely outside the ability of the Codeigniter system. System was not developed for level of control needed. Have considered outsourcing to India so I can return to where the fun is FRONT END :)

Comment: Very sorry, but must close this thread now. This problem has entered it's 2nd year. Psychologically, I can't do this anymore. Mysql & front end are enjoyable. PHP makes me insanely depressed, and isn't worth a human life. Very sorry I can't mark this solved for you. This type of work is better subbed out to the Asian market. They can answer this for you. I can't. This thread and all discussion is now and forever terminated as this is immpractical and undesirable. Please delete this thread, I mistakenly posted an impossible scenario. My bad.